# The mappings App\Entity\xx and App\Entity\are inconsistent with each other

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new on Symfony 6 and i've got problem with 2 of my entities.

App\Entity\Mission :
The mappings App\Entity\Mission#idtagmissionassign and App\Entity\Tag#missionstag are inconsistent with each other.

App\Entity\Tag :
The association App\Entity\Tag#missionstag refers to the inverse side field App\Entity\Mission#tags which does not exist.

This is the relation betewen the 2 entities :
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfGkf.png)

This is Mission entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MissionRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MissionRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'mission')]
class Mission
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $titlemission = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $descriptionmission = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $onsetdate = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $deadline = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $budgetmission = null;

    /*#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $codeapemission = null;*/

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $prioritymission = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Tag::class, inversedBy: 'missionstag',cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name:'mission_tag')]
    private Collection $idtagmissionassign;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'missions')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $iduser = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: User::class, inversedBy: 'missionsassign')]
    private Collection $idmissionassign;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $remote = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->idtagmissionassign = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->idmissionassign = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitlemission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titlemission;
    }

    public function setTitlemission(string $titlemission): self
    {
        $this->titlemission = $titlemission;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescriptionmission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->descriptionmission;
    }

    public function setDescriptionmission(string $descriptionmission): self
    {
        $this->descriptionmission = $descriptionmission;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOnsetdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->onsetdate;
    }

    public function setOnsetdate(\DateTimeInterface $onsetdate): self
    {
        $this->onsetdate = $onsetdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDeadline(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->deadline;
    }

    public function setDeadline(\DateTimeInterface $deadline): self
    {
        $this->deadline = $deadline;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBudgetmission(): ?int
    {
        return $this->budgetmission;
    }

    public function setBudgetmission(int $budgetmission): self
    {
        $this->budgetmission = $budgetmission;

        return $this;
    }

    /*public function getCodeapemission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeapemission;
    }

    public function setCodeapemission(string $codeapemission): self
    {
        $this->codeapemission = $codeapemission;

        return $this;
    }*/

    public function getPrioritymission(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prioritymission;
    }

    public function setPrioritymission(string $prioritymission): self
    {
        $this->prioritymission = $prioritymission;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, tag>
     */
    public function getIdtagmissionassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->idtagmissionassign;
    }

    public function addIdtagmissionassign(tag $idtagmissionassign): self
    {
        if (!$this->idtagmissionassign->contains($idtagmissionassign)) {
            $this->idtagmissionassign->add($idtagmissionassign);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdtagmissionassign(tag $idtagmissionassign): self
    {
        $this->idtagmissionassign->removeElement($idtagmissionassign);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIduser(): ?user
    {
        return $this->iduser;
    }

    public function setIduser(?user $iduser): self
    {
        $this->iduser = $iduser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, user>
     */
    public function getIdmissionassign(): Collection
    {
        return $this->idmissionassign;
    }

    public function addIdmissionassign(user $idmissionassign): self
    {
        if (!$this->idmissionassign->contains($idmissionassign)) {
            $this->idmissionassign->add($idmissionassign);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeIdmissionassign(user $idmissionassign): self
    {
        $this->idmissionassign->removeElement($idmissionassign);

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRemote(): ?string
    {
        return $this->remote;
    }

    public function setRemote(string $remote): self
    {
        $this->remote = $remote;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->titlemission;
    }
}
```

This is Tag entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TagRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TagRepository::class)]
class Tag
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Length(min:2)]
    #[Assert\Valid]
    private ?string $nomtag = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, mappedBy: 'tags')]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name:'mission_tag')]
    private Collection $missionstag;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->missionstag = new ArrayCollection();
    }

//    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, inversedBy:"$idtagmissionassign")]
//    private $genusScientists;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNomtag(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nomtag;
    }

    public function setNomtag(string $nomtag): self
    {
        $this->nomtag = $nomtag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Mission>
     */
    public function getMissions(): Collection
    {
        return $this->missionstag;
    }

    public function addMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if (!$this->missionstag->contains($mission)) {
            $this->missionstag->add($mission);
            $mission->addTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeMission(Mission $mission): self
    {
        if ($this->missionstag->removeElement($mission)) {
            $mission->removeTag($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->nomtag;
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea to help me to solve this problem ?

Many thanks

Change the mappedby and inversedby with no effect.
Trying some stuff follow internet guideline with no success.

Answer (score 1):

`Tag`'s property `missionstag` claims, that it is mapped by `Missions`'s property "`tags`", but there is no such property, instead you have `idtagmissionassign`. (Side note: Your property names are *bad*, because they look like database columns, but you're using an ORM.

The first question you would have to ask yourself: will you need additional columns on your many-to-many table. If the answer is yes, `ORM\ManyToMany` isn't even the right fit. If the answer is no, it fits.

The case where it fits:
**Mission** should have the following property + attributes:

```php
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Tag::class, inversedBy: 'missions', cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'mission_tag')] 
    private Collection $tags;
```

and the **Tag** should have the following property + attributes:

```php
    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Mission::class, mappedBy: 'tags', cascade: ['persist'])]
    #[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'mission_tag')] // <- is this the actual table name?
    private Collection $missions;
```

the `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` must match the **property** name on the other entity, respectively.

If your `mission_tag` table doesn't have columns `mission_id` and `tag_id`, you might have to explicitly name the columns via the [`JoinColumn` and `InverseJoinColumn` Attibutes](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/attributes-reference.html#jointable).

For the case, where it doesn't fit, you would have to have an actual entity MissionTags with OneToMany on Mission/Tag that both reference it, and reversed ManyToOnes on MissionTags. But that wasn't what you asked.